# Building a subset of boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

I'm trying to build only a subset of boost libraries. For example, I have this code:

test.cpp:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main (){
    return 0;
}
```

I then do

```
./bcp --scan test.cpp ~/dev/boost_compact/
```

So the dependencies files are copied to `~/dev/boost_compact/boost`.

Then, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439402/building-a-subset-of-boost-in-windows), I copy all files at the root of a regular boost and also the tools directory and run

```
./bootstrap
./bjam
./bjam install
```

This does copy all the headers to a destination directory, but it does not build/copy the libraries. This same set of actions does work in the full boost. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem. The reason the libraries were not being copied was that I was using the wrong boost directory, that is

```
./bcp --scan --boost=<path to boost build directory> test.cpp ~/dev/boost_compact/
```

when I should be using

```
./bcp --scan --boost=<path to boost source directory> test.cpp ~/dev/boost_compact/
```

If now you run

```
./bootstrap
./bjam
./bjam install
```

The libraries will be build.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a permission issue?

or

Perhaps try explicitly setting the libdir?

```
bjam --libdir=path/to/lib install
```