# How to build & install only a specific part of boost library?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, installation

I have downloaded the latest version of boost library from [here](http://www.boost.org/users/download/). After unzipping it and executing the `bootstrap.sh` script, I have to execute `b2`:

> Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:
>
> ```
> ./b2
> ```

Which will build and install all boost components. Is there any way to run ./b2 to only install specific parts of boost that I need? Like only `system` and `test`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a subset of boost libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050653/building-a-subset-of-boost-libraries)

Comment: @benjymous irrelevant.

Comment: Is it? - that question shows how to build and install subset of boost libraries, which is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use Boost BCP. I have used it in the past to do what you want to do. It is also possible to do other things like changing the boost namespace so that it is called something else(which is useful if you ever want to link two different boost versions into the same application.)

Comment: I could not get it working. Please give me some specific commands to use in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 .\b2.exe --with-system --with-test
```